# Does SQL have a smart JOIN algorithm?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, optimization

let say i have three tables,

```
foo (id serial, one text, two text, three text, four text);
bar (id serial, ...)
foobar (foo_id, bar_id)
```

imagine foo has more than four text columns and millions of row in it.
And foobar just few entries with only foo_id equals to 5

is

```
SELECT *
FROM foo f
JOIN foobar fb ON (fb.foo_id = f.id)
JOIN bar b ON (fb.bar_id = b.id)
WHERE foo_id = 5;
```

going to be optimized ? is the WHERE clause going to be executed after all the table has been JOINed ? or is the WHERE gonna be smart and only select the rows before the JOIN clauses ?

If the former.. shouldn't I write

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE foo_id=5) fb
JOIN foo f ON (fb.foo_id = f.id)
JOIN bar b ON (fb.bar_id = b.id);
```

? to get the process faster ?

Comment: It will optimize your query. You can always use `ANALYZE` to see what is gonna happen

Comment: The only possible answer is "it depends", it depends on a large number of factors.

Comment: General rule: With SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. It's the job of the [*optimizer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_optimization) to (try to) work out the best way to produce the result.

Comment: It is probably worth reading [this article on "Which is faster?" questions](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). For what it is worth I used your demo schema to set up an [SQL Fiddle to compare the execution plans](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/41e04/2) of the two queries and they are the same.

Comment: Logically WHERE is processed **after** JOIN, but every decent optimizer will do it before (at least for Inner Joins)

Comment: Check the execution plan. @Adassko: you mean `explain analyze`, `analyze` on its own will not show the execution plan.

Comment: @GarethD but what if the number of rows is very heavy ?

Comment: The number of rows is irrelevant, both queries are logically the same, Postgresql is smart enough to know this so will almost certainly use the same plan to get the data. Remember, you are telling the optmiser what you want to retrieve, not how you want to retrieve it.

Comment: Could you show us the results (for both queries) from EXPLAIN ANALYZE at http://explain.depesz.com ?

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer should be able to optimize the first query. You can use the `ANALYZE`command to check that you get a good execution plan with low cost.

You need to make sure there are fairly correct table statistics and that there are relevant indexes. I assume `foo_id` and `bar_id` are primary keys, so the indexes should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Join ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_optimization) is one of the most trivial, basic optimization any query optimizer will consider. And yes, PostgreSQL will use it. Read more details at [Controlling the Planner with Explicit JOIN Clauses](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/explicit-joins.html).

You should focus in providing appropriate indexes. Both `foo` and `bar` need an index on `id`, and `foobar` usually needs both index on `(foo_id, bar_id)` *and* and index on `(bar_id, foo_id)`.

Rewriting the query like you propose is no-op. The subquery will likely be pulled up, read [Inside the
PostgreSQL Query Optimizer](http://www.neilconway.org/talks/optimizer/optimizer.pdf):

> We try to pull up FROM-list subqueries to become joins
>   in the parent query